# having trouble changing the color of a button in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am new at kivy/pyhton (and programming in general).
I'm trying to create a mastermind-like game. So basically you press 4 buttons trying to guess the correct color combination and if you win, a message pops up saying that you won.

But the thing that I'm struggling with is the fact that I want the user to be able to press the same button multiple times and that each time the button is clicked, it's color changes.

### So far I've come up with this (kv file):

```
    Button:
        id: b11
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.36, "y": 0.70}
        size_hint: 0.065, 0.065
        
        background_normal: ""
        background_color: (0,0,0,0)
        on_release: root.btn_action()

        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: (1,1,1,0.2)
            Ellipse:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
                size: (45, 45)
```

---

### And this (py file):

```
def btn_action(self):
    global rgba = []
    red = [1, 0, 0, 1]  
    green = [0, 1, 0, 1]  
    blue = [0, 0, 1, 1]  
    purple = [1, 0, 1, 1]
    grey = [1,1,1,0.2]
    if rgba == grey:
        rgba = red
```

---

When I run the code, it tells me that rgba is not defined (which btw I do not know how to define) and thus gives me a syntax error.

I've also tried to work with the button's id, it didn't crash the programm but it also didn't do anything:

### py file

```
def btn_action(self):
    b11 = ListProperty("")
    self.b11 = (1,0,0,1)
```

---

It's probably a stupid mistake and I'm sorry for my newbie-ness, but any help is welcome!

Comment: `global rgba = []` (in your example) comes up as a syntax error when I run it.  You must have added that when you got the problem you mention.  Please fix the question or the code.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

After relearning some kivy and help from creative googling, I created this fully unoptimized example of how you could do what you are attempting:

kivy_button_click.kv:

```
MyButton:
    id: b11
    pos_hint: {"x": 0.36, "y": 0.70}
    size_hint: 0.065, 0.065

    background_normal: ""
    background_color: (0,0,0,0)
    on_release: root.btn_action()

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.rgba
        Ellipse:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            size: (45, 45)
```

And Kivy_Button_Click.py:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import ListProperty

red = [1, 0, 0, 1]
green = [0, 1, 0, 1]
blue = [0, 0, 1, 1]
purple = [1, 0, 1, 1]
grey = [1,1,1,0.2]

class MyButton(Button):
    rgba = ListProperty()

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.rgba = grey

    def btn_action(self):
        if self.rgba == grey:
            self.rgba = red
        elif self.rgba == red:
            self.rgba = green
        elif self.rgba == green:
            self.rgba = purple
        elif self.rgba == purple:
            self.rgba = blue
        else:
            self.rgba = grey

class Kivy_Button_ClickApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Kivy_Button_ClickApp().run()
```

This should at least get you a little closer.
I don't know what you'll need to do for multiple buttons.